# Is it possible to absolutely position content without setting a height?

Tags: css, layout, css-position, swipe, alignment

I have the following basic markup for a site:

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="content_container">
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

I would like to be able to position the three content divs so that they are horizontally aligned ***with only one visible at a time so that I can swipe left and right between them***.

The catch is that each of the three divs contain varying amounts of content and thus have different heights by default.

Is it possible to allow the divs to retain their default height and still force the footer to appear right under the content (no matter which of the three content divs is currently displayed) without having to resort to using JS properties like `offsetHeight`, etc.?

I'm thinking that using absolute positioning is the only way to do what I want, but as soon as absolute positioning is used, the footer moves all the way up to right under the header because the content container div is interpreted as having a height of 0.

Comment: depends on the `display` value of the CSS class.

Comment: Shivan, could you please be a bit more specific in your comment? Thank you.

Comment: try in jsFiddle with `display: table` and `display: inline` . They auto-resize to content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/ZRE3s/

The jquery snippet is just for demonstration, I'm not at all proficient in javascript. But the snippet basically adds a class to the container when a column is clicked.

The markup is similar to yours except i'm using my own class names but it's intuitive enough.

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='col-1'></div>
    <div class='col-2'></div>
    <div class='col-3'></div>
</div>    
<div class='footer'>Footer</div>
```

The columns initially have a `max-height` of `0` (you can use `height`, but I used `max-height` otherwise CSS transitions wont animate height). The columns are given 100% width so they'll take up the width of the container. They're then set horizontally with `display: inline-block` and container's `white-space` set to `nowrap`. The container also has `overflow: hidden` so that we don't get horizontal scroll-bars. So, only the active column would have a height, others would be collapsed.

Basically, every column except for active column has zero height and since the container has `height: auto;` it will take the active column's height.

I feel like I've rambled here, I hope you've understood the gist.

Comment: This is a great solution. Very creative. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If your "content_container" div is appropriately positioned *horizontally* on your page then you can add a float on your content_container and clear the float on the footer to always have it position below your content_container.

```
.content_container {
  float: left;
}

.footer {
  clear: both;
}
```

UPDATE: Here you go with the full markup and CSS: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FfZNM/)**.
I have used colors to show the positioning of different divs.

Comment: If float: left moves your content_container to an extreme left spot where you don't want it to be, then there are other ways to position that as well. Let me know if the above works and then we can tweak it to you liking.

Comment: This doesn't seem to make a difference because all three content divs are absolutely positioned, which gives the container a default height of 0. I would ideally like the container div to stretch to the height of the displayed content div as well as get the footer to be below the content. I was wondering if this was possible with pure CSS, but if not, I will use something like `offsetHeight` in JS to manually set the height of the content div. Thank you.

Comment: Dont make the content divs absolutely positioned. Instead add overflow: auto to the .content_container. That should make the content_container automatically expand to contain the height of the content divs and force the footer down.

Comment: Just added a jsFiddle link to my answer above: http://jsfiddle.net/FfZNM/. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: amitsaurav, thanks for all your help. However, I still don't see how your fiddle helps me because what I want is for only one content div to be displayed at a time with the header and footer. I don't see how that's possible using floating. If I am missing something, please let me know. Thanks.